# Adding words in bold to table using python-docx

Tags: python-docx

I'm new here (and to python) so any feedback on my post is welcome.

I have some code which asks for an input and then adds it to an entry in various tables.

e.g

```
import docx
doc = docx.Document('ABC.docx')
length = len(doc.tables) 
name = input("What is your name?")
x = range(0,length)
for r in x:
    doc.tables[r].cell(0, 1).text = name + ": " + doc.tables[r].cell(0, 1).text
doc.save("ABC_.docx")
```

and this will take text like "I love you" and change it to "Bob: I love you", which is great. However, I'd like the Bob to appear in bold. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure this is the perfect way to do this, but it works. Basically you store the current cell text in a variable then clear the cell. After that, get the first `paragraph` of the cell and add formatted `runs` of text to it, as follows:

```python
import docx

name = input("What is your name?")

doc = docx.Document('ABC.docx')
length = len(doc.tables) 
x = range(0,length)
for r in x:
    celltext = doc.tables[r].cell(0, 1).text
    doc.tables[r].cell(0, 1).text = ""
    paragraph = doc.tables[r].cell(0, 1).paragraphs[0]
    paragraph.add_run(name).bold = True
    paragraph.add_run(": " + celltext)

doc.save("ABC_.docx")
```

Input:

```
What is your name?NewCoder
```

Result:

[image]